# Is this a thing: Generalisation of the Petersen graph

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Let $G$ be a labeled graph on $\{1,2,...,n\}$ and let $G^\prime$ be the labeled complement of this graph. Let H be the graph on $2n$ vertices by taking the disjoint union of $G$ and $G^\prime$ and then adding an edge between vertex $i$ of $G$ and vertex $i$ of $G^\prime.$

If $G=C_5$ then this graph $H$ is just the Petersen graph. I am not sure what to call the general construction... the $G-$tersen graph? I can imagine this being a thing, but I don't recall seeing it. Is it a thing?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedPetersenGraph.html ?

Comment: It's the first thing that leapt out at me, looking at the Petersen graph. I havent investigated it much yet.